# Is it possible to modify incoming Push Notification Text on iOS

Tags: ios, mobile, push-notification

I have a usecase where a notification provider ends up sending me push notification text in a format that I'd like to change. Can I do so in the app's ObjectiveC/Swift code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't change the notification alert message(text), which user will see when app is not in foreground state. The use will see the same text what the notification payload contains.

Comment: Why do you share misinformation?

Answer (score 23):

Since **iOS 10**, it is possible to modify the text of push notifications (unless they are silent notifications) by creating a UNNotificationServiceExtension for your application.

The extension is created as a separate Target in Xcode and provides a NotificationService class with two functions, one that allows you to modify the content of the push notification (*didReceive withContentHandler*) and one that notifies your application if *didReceive withContentHandler* did not complete in time (*serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire*).

For this to work, the push notification that is sent to your application also needs to be modified to include the key/value pair **mutable-content** with a value of **1** so that iOS knows to invoke the UNNotificationServiceExtension for your application.

Apple's [UNNotificationServiceExtension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension) Documentation

Comment: Since this behaviour changed, this should now be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your iOS app does not get a chance to modify the incoming push notification data before it is displayed to the user.